# Scroll element jumping on page load

Tags: css, scroll, load

I have been working on a [site](http://julimtest.co.nf/) for a friend and as I'm trained as a designer I usually tend to work with a theme then just changing various elements in the CSS.

I have got this scroll element which animates the type on the site when the user scrolls, but it jumps into position whenever the user loads the page.

I've been trying to work out what is causing this to happen, and I think it might have to do with either positioning or site responsiveness.

I guess it would be cool if someone could point me in the right direction for, how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It's because one of your js extensions is adding inline styling to the container of the image while your page is still loading. You might want to prevent showing the page until the responsible code or all js is loaded.

Comment: Okay thank you! I'll look into this, but the whole js thing I find really confusing, particularly where to place the code